# List groupby or sorting

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting, xamarin.forms

I m trying to group a list using c# program on Xamarin .

List EList; 
Sample Data is
ExpList(Item, dop,Value)

grocery 01/03/2019 1000
clothes 04/03/2019 250
grocery 01/04/2019 500
movie   02/03/2018 550
clothes 02/05/2019 550

I want to group the list by Item Name and need to calculate its total Value . ie. 
Group the list 
grocery 01/03/2019 1000
grocery 01/04/2019 500
clothes 04/03/2019 250
clothes 02/05/2019 550
movie   02/03/2018 550

Calculate 
I want some information on group like below 
Total group Items is 3 
grocery Number of times  2 and Value is 1500
clothes Number of times  2 and Value is 800
movie Number of times  1 and Value is 550

Comment: `list.GroupBy(x => x.Item).Select(x => new { Item = x.Key, Total = x.Sum(y => y.Value.Value) }).ToList();`

Comment: this is already well documented: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/ListView/Grouping/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the following code

```
public class People
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}


List<People> peopleList = new List<People>()
        {
            new People { Name="grocery ",Date="01/03/2019",Value=1000 },
            new People { Name="clothes ",Date="02/03/2019",Value=250 },
            new People { Name="grocery ",Date="04/03/2019",Value=500 },
            new People { Name="clothes ",Date="01/02/2019",Value=550 },
            new People { Name="movie ",Date="03/03/2019",Value=550 },

        };


var groupList = peopleList.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => new { name = x.Key,Total=x.Sum(y=>y.Value),Num=x.Distinct().Count() }).Distinct().ToList();

Console.WriteLine("Total group Items is "+groupList.Count() );

foreach(var item in groupList)
{
  Console.WriteLine(item.name + " Number of times "+ item.Num + " and Value is " + item.Total);
}
```